# Probabilities involving Beurling density

Tags: pr.probability, sampling

I am interested in calculating probabilities involving Beurling densities. Since it's likely probabilists are not familiar with the definitions, I give them below.

**Definitions.**

A metric space is *uniformly discrete* if for any distinct $x,y$ we have $\exists\varepsilon\;:\;(\forall x,y\in A:d(x,y)>\varepsilon)$, i.e there's a minimal separation of points.
Define $$\begin{gathered}\nu^{+}(r)=\text{largest number of points of }A\text{ found in every }B(x,r)\\
\nu^{-}(r)=\text{smallest number of points of }A\text{ found in every }B(x,r)
\end{gathered}$$ and then define *upper and lower Beurling densities* by:
$$\begin{gathered}D^{+}(\Lambda)=\limsup_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\nu^{+}(r)}{r^{d}}\\
D^{-}(\Lambda)=\liminf_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\nu^{-}(r)}{r^{d}}
\end{gathered}$$ A set with $D^{+}(\Lambda)=D^{-}(\Lambda)$ is said to have *uniform Beurling density*.

**The Problem.**

I would like some help in finding a method (or reference) for computing probabilities involving Beurling densities of randomly sampled finite (hence uniformly discrete) sets, depending on the number of samples. I'm having trouble working with the definition. For example:

- Living in $\mathbb R^d$, suppose I have points $X=\left\{x_1,\dots,x_n \right\}$ independently sampled from a Poisson distribution.  Let us take the $\alpha$-translations of this set in the direction of each axis i.e the union of $(X+\alpha \hat x_k)$ for all $1\leq k \leq d$, and call it $\bar X$. What's the probability, depending on $n,\alpha$, that $D^-(\bar X)>a$?

A more difficult question is:

- Suppose $X$ is a finite set of points drawn independetly from *some* a probability measure $\mu$. Given $D^-(\bar X)>a$, what's the probability that $d_H(X,\operatorname{supp}\mu)<b$, depending on $n$ and $\alpha$? ($d_H$ denotes hausdorff distance)

**Nice bounds on these probabilities would be fantastic as well!**